# What are the normal subgroups of the finite Coxeter Groups of type Bn?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $B_n = \langle \rho_0,\rho_1,\ldots,\rho_{n-1} \rangle$ subject to the relations that $(\rho_i\rho_j)^{m_{i,j}} = id$ with $m_{i,i} = 1$, $m_{i,j} = 2$ for $|i-j|\ge 2$, $m_{i,i+1} =3$ for $0 \le i <n-1$ and finally  $m_{n-1,n} =4$. What are the normal subgroups of $B_n$ and where might I find a reference? Computationally, I see that for all $n>4$ there are 9 of them and I would like to find some source which describes them explicitly.

Comment: I don't know a reference, but it's an exercise to determine them. This is the wreath product $C_2\wr_n S_n$. The normal subgroups contained in $C_2^n$ are $4$ many: $0$, the constants (of order $2$), the sum 0 subgroup $(C_2^n)_0$ (of index $2$) and the whole $C_2^n$. Others intersect $C_2^n$ at least in the sum $0$ subgroup. If the intersection is $C_2^n$, we get the 2 nontrivial normal subgroups of $S_n$. If the intersection is $(C_2^n)_0$: the quotient by the latter is $S_n\times C_2$. Its nontrivial normal subgroups not containing $C_2$ are $A_n$ and $S_n$. This gives $9$ normal subgroups.

Comment: (I used $n\ge 5$ in using the classification of normal subgroups of $S_n$. Also $n\ge 3$ is used at some point because I used that the action modulo constants is non-trivial.)

Comment: Here you find a reference (including not just type $B_n$, but all irreducble finite Coxeter groups): https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-london-mathematical-society/article/normal-subgroups-of-finite-and-affine-coxeter-groups/7DB67D2BB3F038C76AB0AB90C814FFDA